# How to parse milliseconds?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, strptime

How do I use `strptime` or any other functions to parse time stamps with milliseconds in R?

```
time <- "2010-01-15 13:55:23.975"
print(time)
# [1] "2010-01-15 13:55:23.975"
strptime(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
# [1] NA
strptime(time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "2010-01-15 13:55:23"`
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Courtesy of the `?strptime` help file (with the example changed to your value):

```
> z <- strptime("2010-01-15 13:55:23.975", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
> z # prints without fractional seconds
[1] "2010-01-15 13:55:23 UTC"

> op <- options(digits.secs=3)
> z
[1] "2010-01-15 13:55:23.975 UTC"

> options(op) #reset options
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the strptime doc. I was looking for a format character and gave up when I did not see one.

Comment: so would I! The "%OS" bit is awesome.

Comment: Is this only in python3 or something?  In my python2.7.8:

    >>> time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/opt/pythons/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 467, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
    File "/opt/pythons/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 317, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
    ValueError: 'O' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS'

Comment: @firebush: It's in R. It might require "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3" on some platforms. The implementation of the "OS" format is labeled as OS-specific on the help pages.

Comment: Is it possible to print milliseconds in the output of `system.time`?

Answer (score 30):

You can also use `strptime(time, "%OSn")` where 0 <= n <= 6, without having to set `digits.secs`.

The documentation states "Which of these are supported is OS-dependent." so YMMV.

Comment: This did not work for me too on the Ubuntu. That's yields NA .

Answer (score 1):

Another option to achive this, without the need to set `options(digits.secs=3)` is using `format()`:

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

# alternative:
format(Sys.time(), digits = 3L)

time <- "2010-01-15 13:55:23.975"

# using strptime to convert the string
format(strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
format(strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), digits = 3L)

# using as.POSIXct to convert the string (under the hood also using strptime())
format(as.POSIXct(time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
format(as.POSIXct(time), digits = 3L)
```

However, regarding `as.POSIXct` please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699511/difference-between-as-posixct-as-posixlt-and-strptime-for-converting-character-v/10700025#10700025).