# How to vectorize and accelerate strtime() logtime conversion on a data-frame

Tags: r, dataframe, string-conversion, date-conversion, vectorization

(EDIT: one of the issues here is scale, namely what works for one row will blow up/crash R on a 200,000 * 50 dataframe. For example, strptime must be applied column-wise, not row-wise, to avoid hanging.
I'm looking for **working code solutions that you actually ran on 200,000 * 50 including your measured runtime**, not just casual "this is easy" remarks. It's easy to get runtimes > 12 hrs if you pick the wrong fn. Next, I also asked you to make my zero-time adjustment code faster, the job's not finished till that's done. Noone attempted that so far.)

---

I want to **vectorize and accelerate the following multistep log-time conversion, with millisecond accuracy, involving  converting *`strtime()`* to a single numeric, followed by subtraction and then *`log()`* on a large data-frame** (200,000 rows * 300 cols; other (non-time) columns omitted).
Code below.
As well as making it vectorized and fast, an extra problem is I'm **not sure how best to represent the (higher-dimensional) intermediate values at each step** e.g. as list from strtime, matrix, vector). I already tried *`apply,sapply,lapply,vapply,ddply::maply(),...`* but the incompatibility of intermediate format(s) keeps messing me up...

**Each row has 50 columns *time1..time50* (chr, format="HH:MM:SS.sss") representing time as string in millisecond resolution.** I need millisecond accuracy.
Within each row, columns *time1..time50* are in non-decreasing order, and I want to **convert them into log of time before *time50***. The conversion fn *`parse_hhmmsecms()`* is at bottom, and needs serious vectorization and speeding up, you can see alternative versions commented out. What I figured so far: *`strtime()`* is faster than (multiple) *`substr()`* calls, I then convert somehow to list of three numeric *`(hh,mm,sec.ms)`*, then convert to vector assuming the next step should be to vector-multiply with *`%*% c(3600,60,1)`* to convert to numeric seconds.
Here is pseudocode of what I do for each row, and each time-string; full code is at bottom:

```
 for each row in dataframe { # vectorize this, loop_apply(), or whatever...
 #for each time-column index i ('time1'..'time50') { # vectorize this...
 hhmmsecms_50 <- parse_hhmmsecms(xx$time50[i])
 # Main computation
 xx[i,Clogtime] <- -10*log10(1000*(hhmmsecms_50 - parse_hhmmsecms(xx[i,Ctime]) ))
 # Minor task: fix up all the 'zero-time' events to be evenly spaced between -3..0
 #}
 }
```

So there are five subproblems involved:

1. How to vectorize handling the list returned by *`strtime()`*? since it returns a list of 3 items, when passed a 2D dataframe or 1D row of time-strings, we will get a 3D or 2D intermediate object. (do we internally we use list-of-list? matrix of lists? array of lists?)
2. How to vectorize the entire function *`parse_hhmmsecms()`*?
3. Then do the subtraction and log
4. Vectorize the zero-time fixup code as well (this is now the slowest part by far)
5. How to accelerate steps 1...4.?

Code snippet below using ten example columns *`time41..50`*  (use *`random_hhmmsecms()`* if you want a bigger sample)

I did my best to follow [these recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), this is as reproducible as I can get it in six hours' work:

```
# Each of 200,000 rows has 50 time strings (chr) like this...    
xx <- structure(list(time41 = c("08:00:41.465", "08:00:50.573", "08:00:50.684"
), time42 = c("08:00:41.465", "08:00:50.573", "08:00:50.759"), 
    time43 = c("08:00:41.465", "08:00:50.573", "08:00:50.759"
    ), time44 = c("08:00:41.465", "08:00:50.664", "08:00:50.759"
    ), time45 = c("08:00:41.465", "08:00:50.684", "08:00:50.759"
    ), time46 = c("08:00:42.496", "08:00:50.684", "08:00:50.759"
    ), time47 = c("08:00:42.564", "08:00:50.759", "08:00:51.373"
    ), time48 = c("08:00:48.370", "08:00:50.759", "08:00:51.373"
    ), time49 = c("08:00:50.573", "08:00:50.759", "08:00:54.452"
    ), time50 = c("08:00:50.573", "08:00:50.759", "08:00:54.452"
    )), .Names = c("time41", "time42", "time43", "time44", "time45", 
"time46", "time47", "time48", "time49", "time50"), row.names = 3:5, class = "data.frame")

# Handle millisecond timing and time conversion
options('digits.secs'=3)

# Parse "HH:MM:SS.sss" timestring into (numeric) number of seconds (Very slow)
parse_hhmmsecms <- function(t) {
  as.numeric(substr(t,1,2))*3600 + as.numeric(substr(t,4,5))*60 + as.numeric(substr(t,7,12)) # WORKS, V SLOW

  #c(3600,60,1) %*% sapply((strsplit(t[1,]$time1, ':')), as.numeric) # SLOW, NOT VECTOR

  #as.vector(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(t,':',fixed=TRUE)))) %*% c(3600,60,1) # WANT TO VECTORIZE THIS
}

random_hhmmsecms <- function(n=1, min=8*3600, max=16*3600) {
# Generate n random hhmmsecms objects between min and max (8am:4pm)
xx <- runif(n,min,max)
ss <- xx %%  60
mm <- (xx %/% 60) %% 60
hh <- xx %/% 3600
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%05.3f", hh,mm,ss)
}

xx$logtime45 <- xx$logtime44 <- xx$logtime43 <- xx$logtime42  <- xx$logtime41  <- NA
xx$logtime50 <- xx$logtime49 <- xx$logtime48 <- xx$logtime47  <- xx$logtime46  <- NA

# (we pass index vectors as the dataframe column ordering may change) 
Ctime <- which(colnames(xx)=='time41') : which(colnames(xx)=='time50')
Clogtime <- which(colnames(xx)=='logtime41') : which(colnames(xx)=='logtime50')
for (i in 40:nrow(xx)) {
  #if (i%%100==0) { print(paste('... row',i)) }

  hhmmsecms_50 <- parse_hhmmsecms(xx$time50[i])
  xx[i,Clogtime] <- -10*log10(1000*(hhmmsecms_50 - parse_hhmmsecms(xx[i,Ctime]) ))

  # Now fix up all the 'zero-time' events to be evenly spaced between -3..0
  Czerotime.p <- which(xx[i,Clogtime]==Inf | xx[i,Clogtime]>-1e-9)
  xx[i,Czerotime.p] <- seq(-3,0,length.out=length(Czerotime.p))  
}
```

Comment: Look at the vectorized built in strptime function and related POSICct and POSIXlt classes.  You can actually apply strptime over a vector and convert it to numeric.  There are many built in time handling functions.

Comment: John, no, I tried that weeks ago, *`as.POSIXlt()`* conversion discards milliseconds (chron and zoo appear similarly unuseable).

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds-in-r) in my first Google search attempt. (It was the very first result, in fact.)

Comment: In fact asPOSIXlt does store ms but not display them, unless you use options('digits.secs'=3) (which I already had in my code, but commented out)

Comment: The zero-time fixup code (not the strptime part) is now the slowest part, noone has attempted that yet. Please post your actual runtime on 200,000 * 50 dataframe or similar. I currently get > 12 hrs.

Answer (score 2):

You may be overcomplicating things.

Start with base classes which *do* milliseconds very well (and on appropriate operating systems even microseconds) but note that

1. you need to set `options("digits.secs"=7)` (that's the max that can be displayed) to see them displayed
2. you need an additional parsing character for `strptime` et al

all of which is in the docs, and countless examples here on SO.

Quick examples:

```
R> someTime <- ISOdatetime(2011, 12, 27, 2, 3, 4.567)
R> someTime
[1] "2011-12-27 02:03:04.567 CST"
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> now
[1] "2011-12-27 16:48:20.247298 CST"      # microsecond display on Linux
R> 
R> txt <- "2001-02-03 04:05:06.789123"
R> strptime(txt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")    # note the %0S for sub-seconds
[1] "2001-02-03 04:05:06.789123"
R>
```

And key functions such as `strptime` or `as.POSIXct` are all vectorised and you can throw entire columns at them.

Comment: thanks but the dataset comes as a csv, if you read in the dates and do strptime in colClasses I seem to recall it blows up memory hugely. I'll retry it in slices. A second reason it's undesirable to store times with a fake date e.g. "2001-02-03" is since I print them, compare them (< > ==), manipulate them, aggregate by them, use them as graph or histogram labels etc. But yeah I can use *`as.numeric(strptime(...) - origin_date)`*

Comment: You *can* and maybe *should* do arithmetic on `Date` and `POSIXct` classes.  If you only have hours:mins:secs, maybe append them onto a nominal base date of 2001-01-01 or something.  The memory issue is known, that sadly seems to be the price we have to pay for the general usability of `strptime`.

Comment: The zero-time fixup code is now the slow part, would you please address that too? Doing the zero-time fixup row-wise takes > 12hrs. Please post your actual runtime on 200,000 * 50 dataframe or similar.