# Difference between as.POSIXct/as.POSIXlt and strptime for converting character vectors to POSIXct/POSIXlt

Tags: r, date, time, benchmarking

I have followed a number of questions here that asks about how to convert character vectors to datetime classes. I often see 2 methods, the strptime and the as.POSIXct/as.POSIXlt methods. I looked at the 2 functions but am unclear what the difference is.

### strptime

```
function (x, format, tz = "") 
{
    y <- .Internal(strptime(as.character(x), format, tz))
    names(y$year) <- names(x)
    y
}
<bytecode: 0x045fcea8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

### as.POSIXct

```
function (x, tz = "", ...) 
UseMethod("as.POSIXct")
<bytecode: 0x069efeb8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

### as.POSIXlt

```
function (x, tz = "", ...) 
UseMethod("as.POSIXlt")
<bytecode: 0x03ac029c>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Doing a microbenchmark to see if there are performance differences:

```
library(microbenchmark)
Dates <- sample(c(dates = format(seq(ISOdate(2010,1,1), by='day', length=365), format='%d-%m-%Y')), 5000, replace = TRUE)
df <- microbenchmark(strptime(Dates, "%d-%m-%Y"), as.POSIXlt(Dates, format = "%d-%m-%Y"), times = 1000)

Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1 as.POSIXlt(Dates, format = "%d-%m-%Y") 32.38596 33.81324 34.78487 35.52183 61.80171
2            strptime(Dates, "%d-%m-%Y") 31.73224 33.22964 34.20407 34.88167 52.12422
```

strptime seems slightly faster. so what gives? why would there be 2 similar functions or are there differences between them that I missed?

Comment: If you want to see what code is being called when calling `as.POSIXct` and `as.POSIXlt` on character vectors, look at `as.POSIXct.default` and `as.POSIXlt.character`, respectively.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Well, the functions do different things.

First, there are two internal implementations of date/time: `POSIXct`, which stores seconds since UNIX epoch (+some other data), and `POSIXlt`, which stores a list of day, month, year, hour, minute, second, etc.

`strptime` is a function to directly convert character vectors (of a variety of formats) to `POSIXlt` format.

`as.POSIXlt` converts a variety of data types to `POSIXlt`. It tries to be intelligent and do the sensible thing - in the case of character, it acts as a wrapper to `strptime`.

`as.POSIXct` converts a variety of data types to `POSIXct`. It also tries to be intelligent and do the sensible thing - in the case of character, it runs `strptime` first, then does the conversion from `POSIXlt` to `POSIXct`.

It makes sense that `strptime` is faster, because `strptime` only handles character input whilst the others try to determine which method to use from input type. It should also be a bit safer in that being handed unexpected data would just give an error, instead of trying to do the intelligent thing that might not be what you want.

Comment: great answer. is there a consensus on which is best practice for compiling data for modeling or data visualization purposes?

Answer (score 31):

There are two POSIXt types, POSIXct and POSIXlt. "ct" can stand for calendar time, it stores the number of seconds since the origin. "lt", or local time, keeps the date as a list of time attributes (such as "hour" and "mon").
Try these examples:

```
date.hour=strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

date=c("26/10/2016")

time=c("19:51:30")

day<-paste(date,"T", time)

day.time1=as.POSIXct(day,format="%d/%m/%Y T %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Paris")

day.time1

day.time1$year

day.time2=as.POSIXlt(day,format="%d/%m/%Y T %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Paris")

day.time2

day.time2$year
```

Comment: Great! `attributes()` is also interesting. Perhaps yop should add this ;-)