# as.POSIXlt ignores tz argument

Tags: r

Pretty basic, just not understanding what the tz argument is for if not for this...

```
dateIWantToConvert <- as.Date("2013-06-01") #the format of my starting object

as.POSIXlt(dateIWantToConvert, tz="America/Chicago")
[1] "2013-06-01 UTC"
```

There are a whole lot of these in a data.frame, so efficiency is important.

Comment: The `tz` argument is used when you're passing `as.POSIXlt`  a character string, not a `date` object.  The `date` object already has a timezone, so the `tz` value in `as.POSIXlt` is ignored.

Comment: @Mekki:  `attributes(as.Date("2013-06-01"))` doesn't show tzone attribute.  How does one determine the timezone of a `date`, POSIXct or POSIXlt

Comment: @DaveX I'm not sure. The whole thing is a mess. The DateTimeClasses help file is dense and hard to understand.  Users are getting frustrated enough that I hope this will be a priority to revise soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reliable way to do this is to use `strptime`. This takes any `tz` arguement from `OlsonNames()`. And by reliable, I mean that this should be OS independent.

```
(vec.Date <- strptime("2013-06-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "America/Chicago"))
# "2013-06-01 CDT"
class(vec.Date)
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

And for your question regarding efficiency, you really should be using `strptime`. See [Difference between as.POSIXct/as.POSIXlt and strptime for converting character vectors to POSIXct/POSIXlt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699511/difference-between-as-posixct-as-posixlt-and-strptime-for-converting-character-v)

Answer (score 3):

You could try without `as.Date()`:

```
> as.POSIXlt("2013-06-01", tz="America/Chicago")
#[1] "2013-06-01 CDT"
```

Comment: assume it's already as.Date()ed, I included that for the example because my original object was in that format. I'll edit so that's more clear.

Comment: `?POSIXlt` states "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC." So if you supply a parameter that is already in "Date" format, it includes the tz as UTC (and this seems to override other specifications).

Comment: If they're already `as.Date()`ed, wherever that object is created, ensure it has a time & timezone component.  See update to my answer.

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay I don't think that a `Date` object has a time zone. At least, there is no hint that it has in the documentation.

Comment: The `base:as.Date` documentation suggests otherwise.  See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html

Answer (score 0):

As per `?timezones`, invalid timezones are treated as `UTC` often without a warning.  It's likely that your specific environment doesn't know how to interpret "America/Chicago".  The documentation points out that it's inconsistent.

Try using `"CDT"` instead of "America/Chicago".  Alternatively, there are details in `?timezones` about how to feed R a list of timezone formats to interpret.

UPDATE: `as.Date` returns a "date" object, not a character string.  `as.POSIXlt` will, quote: "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC", from `as.POSIXlt`.  So it seems if `x` is a `date` object in `as.POSIXlt` and it has no time value, the `tz` option is ignored and replaced with `UTC`.

As a result, another option is to ensure that the `date` object passed to `as.POSIXlt` has time & timezone already specified.  Or, convert the object to character string before passing it to `as.POSIXlt` so that it will use its own `tz` option.

Comment: However, "America/Chicago" is one of the time zones listed by `OlsonNames()`. In my case, the OP's code gives the same result as he gets, but if I omit `as.Date`, I get the expected result. `as.POSIXlt("2013-06-01", tz="America/Chicago")`

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Me too.  Investigating.