# time zone printed in list, but attribute blank

Tags: r, datetime

I extract information from a database using the library RODBC.

```
library(RODBC)
stats <- function(user, pswd){
  qry <- " select mydatetime from bar"
  cn <- odbcConnect("A", uid=user, pwd= pswd)
  rst <- sqlQuery(cn, qry, stringsAsFactors = F)
  odbcClose(cn)
  rm(list = c("cn", "qry"))
  rst
}
my_list <- stats("a", "b")
```

I'm puzzled by the output.  This is a POSIXct datetime.  When I `my_list$mydatetime` the list, it is presented like this:

```
  [1] "2018-01-19 14:54:23 CET" "2018-01-19 14:53:22 CET" "2018-01-19 14:52:53 CET" "2018-01-19 14:51:50 CET"
  [5] "2018-01-12 11:32:44 CET" "2018-01-12 11:32:02 CET" "2018-01-19 06:53:35 CET" "2018-01-19 06:52:06 CET"
  [9] "2018-01-16 08:50:46 CET" "2018-01-16 08:49:59 CET" "2018-01-16 08:51:47 CET" "2018-01-15 05:31:53 CET"
```

Notice the `CET`, which is the correct time zone. When I run `attr(my_list$mydatetime,"tzone")` I get `""`.

My question is not how to add a time zone, rather **why is a time zone presented when the list is printed**- this is confusing, as i assume that it is treated as a CET datetime, when in fact it seems to be a date time with out time zone?

Comment: It seems you are right to be puzzled. When I read from DB same thing happens, it seems time zone is set to system time zone. Similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688509/determine-and-set-timezone-in-posixct-posixlt-strptime-etc-in-r. However when I set a new `POSIXct` object `library(lubridate);testTime1<-ymd_hm("2018-01-01 00:00")` time zone is set to UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source for `print.POSIXct` we see the following:

```
print.POSIXct <- function (x, tz = "", usetz = TRUE, ...) 
{
  max.print <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
  FORM <- if (missing(tz)) 
    function(z) format(x, usetz = usetz)
  else function(z) format(x, tz = tz, usetz = usetz)
  if (max.print < length(x)) {
    print(FORM(x[seq_len(max.print)]), ...)
    cat(" [ reached getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
      length(x) - max.print, "entries ]\n")
  }
  else print(if (length(x)) 
    FORM(x)
  else paste(class(x)[1L], "of length 0"), ...)
  invisible(x)
}
```

The key point here is that, regardless of whether or not the "tzone" attribute is populated, `x` is formatted using `format.POSIXct`. Delving down another layer, we can see that `format.POSIXct` looks like this:

```
format.POSIXct <- function (x, format = "", tz = "", usetz = FALSE, ...) 
{
  if (!inherits(x, "POSIXct")) 
    stop("wrong class")
  if (missing(tz) && !is.null(tzone <- attr(x, "tzone"))) 
    tz <- tzone
  structure(format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz), format, usetz, 
    ...), names = names(x))
}
```

Again, if the "tzone" attribute exists, it is propagated through. Whether or not it exists, the `POSIXct` object is coerced into a `POSIXlt` object before printing. Now we drop off a cliff because `as.POSIXlt` has an internal call directly to the R interpreter so we can't debug the source code easily.

We can, however, read the documentation for the `POSIXlt` class (`?POSIXlt`) and we find out that:

> "POSIXlt" objects will often have an attribute "tzone", a character vector of length 3 giving the time zone name from the TZ environment variable and the names of the base time zone and the alternate (daylight-saving) time zone. Sometimes this may just be of length one, giving the time zone name.

So, **`POSIXlt` objects do have a default timezone, taken from the system wide TZ environment variable**. Additionally, we read the next paragraph:

> "POSIXct" objects may also have an attribute "tzone", a character vector of length one. If set to a non-empty value, it will determine how the object is converted to class "POSIXlt" and in particular how it is printed. This is usually desirable, but if you want to specify an object in a particular time zone but to be printed in the current time zone you may want to remove the "tzone" attribute (e.g., by c(x)).

So the "tzone" attribute in the `POSIXct` class is to tell the class what timezone to use when converting to `POSIXlt` (such as for printing) if you **do not** want it to use the **default behavior** of using the local timezone.