# Adding milliseconds to a timestamp in R, even though the original character does not have milliseconds?

Tags: r, timestamp, milliseconds

I am doing some animal movement analysis and I want to submit data to an organisation called [Movebank](https://www.movebank.org/cms/movebank-main) for annotation, but they require the timestamp to have milliseconds included with 3 decimal places.

I have a column in my data frame (dat) with my timestamps as characters (without milliseconds), for example `"2017-07-19 16:30:24"`

To convert them to time and date format with milliseconds I am using the code:

```
options(digits.secs = 3)
dat$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")
```

Which works fine at converting my timestamp column to POSIXct which I can use to make tracks etc., but it does not add .000 milliseconds to the end of each timestamp which I was hoping it would.

I have also tried:

```
dat$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3", tz = "UTC")
```

(Note: I added .. `%OS3` ...)
But this returns an `NA` for my for my timestamps.

Can anybody shed some light on this? I essentially need to add .000 to the end of each of my timestamps so that, using the example given above, I would have the format `"2017-07-19 16:30:24.000"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The milliseconds will be dropped if there are no times with effective milliseconds.

```
options(digits.secs=4)

x1 <- as.POSIXct("2017-07-19 16:30:25")
as.POSIXct(paste0(x1, ".000"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
# [1] "2017-07-19 16:30:25 UTC"
```

However, they will be added automatically if there are.

```
x2 <- as.POSIXct("2017-07-19 16:30:25.002")
c(x1, x2)
# [1] "2017-07-19 18:30:25.000 CEST" "2017-07-19 18:30:25.002 CEST"
```

Comment: Yeah I think that worked. I used: ```dat$timestamp <- paste0(dat$timestamp, ".001")```, then continued with the code I have above.

Comment: @jmccucc Did you get `"2017-07-19 16:30:25.001"` or ``"2017-07-19 16:30:25.000"`` with that?

Comment: I got ```"2017-07-19 16:30:25.000"``` strangely enough, I didn't question it though because it's what I wanted anyway. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: @jmccucc I'm not exactly sure, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10700025/6574038) sheds some light on it. Accordingly it's probably better to use `strptime(paste0(x1, ".001"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")`.