# Showing milli/microsecond timestamp precision

Tags: r, dt

My `POSIXct` timestamps contain microsecond precision which I need to visualise. Is there any concise way to do this with `DT`, or is my only option to transform the `POSIXct` to a string on `R` side?

Here is a tryout minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
        dt <- data.table::data.table(ts = as.POSIXct(1.654321, origin = '1970-01-01'))
        dt[, ts.DT_formatDate := ts]
        dt[, ts.converted_in_r_to_string := format(ts, format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS6Z', tz = 'UTC')]

        DT <- datatable(data = dt)

        DT <- formatDate(
          DT, columns = 'ts.DT_formatDate', method = 'toISOString',
          params =  list('en-US', list(year = 'numeric', month = 'long', day = 'numeric', fractionalSecondDigits = 3))
        )

        DT
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

I don't think [`Moment.js`](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) is implemented in DT. It allows many date/time transformation options on the client side and could be a solution.

Comment: I don't understand, what you expect exactly...

Comment: @Christoph, I expect the same result as `ts.converted_in_r_to_string` but with `DT` transformed on the client side.

Comment: Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289315/5784831 helps? I guess you need POSIXlt in the second case? Let me know, if that solved the problem...