# How to convert specific time format to timestamp in R?

Tags: r, date, formatting, posixct

I am working on "Localization Data for Person Activity Data Set" dataset from UCI and in this data set there is a column of date and time(both in one column) with following format:

```
27.05.2009 14:03:25:777
27.05.2009 14:03:25:183
27.05.2009 14:03:25:210
27.05.2009 14:03:25:237
...
```

I am wondering if there is anyway to convert this column to timestamp using R.

Comment: What would those last three digits represent?

Comment: hello Soroosh. Have a look at the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, we need to substitute the colon separating the milliseconds from the seconds to a dot, otherwise the final step won't work (thanks to [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) for this one). Since in the end R will use the separators it wants, to be quicker, I'll just go ahead and substitute all the colons for dots:

```
x <- "27.05.2009 14:03:25:777"  # this is a simplified version of your data
y <- gsub(":", ".", x)          # this is your vector with the aforementioned substitution
```

By the way, this is how your vector should look after `gsub`:

```
> y
[1] "27.05.2009 14.03.25.777"
```

Now, in order to have it show the milliseconds, you first need to adjust an R option and then use a function called `strptime`, which will convert your date vector to POSIXlt (an R-friendly) format. Just do the following:

```
> options(digits.secs = 3)           # this tells R you want it to consider 3 digits for seconds.
> strptime(y, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")  # this finally formats your vector
[1] "2009-05-27 14:03:25.777"
```

I've learned this nice trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150179/1169233). [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150357/1169233) also says you can skip the `options` setting and use, for example, `strptime(y, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS3")`, but it doesn't work for me. [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712/henrik) noted that the [function's help page, `?strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) states that the `%OS3` bit is OS-dependent. I'm using an updated Ubuntu 13.04 and using `%OS3` yields `NA`.

When using `strptime` (or other POSIX-related functions such as `as.Date`), keep in mind some of the most common conversions used (edited for brevity, as suggested by [DWin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/dwin). Complete list at [`strptime`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)):

- `%a` Abbreviated weekday name in the current locale.
- `%A` Full weekday name in the current locale.
- `%b` Abbreviated month name in the current locale.
- `%B` Full month name in the current locale.
- `%d` Day of the month as decimal number (01–31).
- `%H` Hours as decimal number (00–23). Times such as 24:00:00 are accepted for input.
- `%I` Hours as decimal number (01–12).
- `%j` Day of year as decimal number (001–366).
- `%m` Month as decimal number (01–12).
- `%M` Minute as decimal number (00–59).
- `%p` AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with `%I` and not with `%H`.
- `%S  Second as decimal number (00–61), allowing for up to two leap-seconds (but POSIX-compliant implementations will ignore leap seconds).
- `%U` Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The US convention.
- `%w` Weekday as decimal number (0–6, Sunday is 0).
- `%W` Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 1). The UK convention.
- `%y` Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19
- `%Y` Year with century. Note that whereas there was no zero in the original Gregorian calendar, ISO 8601:2004 defines it to be valid (interpreted as 1BC)

Comment: a) You don't need the long format for `as.Date()`. b) wrap `as.POSIXct()` around `strptime()` and you get the more compact POSIXct. c) You missed the subseconds. That requires a `gsub()` or something else as the format requires a dot; the colon will not work.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks for the heads up, I was wondering if those were really subseconds or what. Honestly, I don't know how to handle them. Would you show us (maybe by editing the post)?

Comment: I think posting the entire table of conversion formats from the help page is a waste of space. Better to just link to a page where someone can find it or just `?strptime`.

Comment: @DWin, I've though about just inserting the ones I thought would be more useful, but you never know when a link might break. Feel free to propose an edit, though.

Comment: I did suggest alternatives. If `?strptime` fails, then the R installation is broken.

Comment: Hey guys thank you all for your answers. Actually my main problems are (1) those last 3 digit number(millisecond) and (2) date format which is date.month.year. I don't know how to handle them before use strptime function!

Comment: @Soroosh, please see edited answer, I think it might resolve your issue now.

Comment: @DWin, I was also trying to account for the laziness of the reader to click on a link, but since I was editing the answer, I went ahead and shortened the list like you suggested.

Comment: Regarding "`strptime(y, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS3")`, but it doesn't work for me", see also the comment to the example in `?strptime`: `## time to sub-second accuracy (**if supported by the OS**);
format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%OS3")`.

Comment: @Henrik, good eye, I'll update the answer.