# Does rpy2 support millisecond timestamps and timestamps with timezones?

Tags: python, r, timestamp, rpy2

I deal with a lot of time series tick data, and am trying to use [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) to get this data from Python into R. Specifically, I'd like to transfer time series that contains millisecond timestamps (critical) and time zone information (nice-to-have).

To test transferring a timestamp, I tried:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

# 1 microsecond into 2015 in US Eastern time
time = datetime(2015,1,1,0,0,0,1, tzinfo = timezone('US/Eastern'))
robjects.r.assign('time', time)
```

But this gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 170, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py", line 96, in __call__
    new_args = [conversion.py2ri(a) for a in args]
  File "C:\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\singledispatch.py", line 210, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python\2.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\conversion.py", line 39, in py2ri
    raise NotImplementedError("Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '%s'" % str(type(obj)))
NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<type 'datetime.datetime'>'
```

Seems like rpy2 does not support `datetime` objects... So how can I transfer time series into R?

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of date/time objects in R.

For example:

```
robjects.POSIXct([time])
```

Once you know, you can quickly add a conversion rule to `rpy2`

Comment: Unfortunately, the milliseconds are dropped by rpy2 when Python `datetime` is converted to R's `POSIXct`. Specifically, `robjects.POSIXct([datetime(2015,1,1,0,0,0,0)]).r_repr() == robjects.POSIXct([datetime(2015,1,1,0,0,0,1)]).r_repr()` is `True`

Comment: Would this help ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds-in-r