# POSIXct doesn't seem to be picking up %H:%M:%S even after putting the format correctly

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, xts

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

library(timeSeries)
library(timeDate)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(tseries)

sessionInfo()

#################################################################################
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tseries_0.10-35               quantmod_0.4-6                TTR_0.23-1                    PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
[5] xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-13                    timeSeries_3022.101.2         timeDate_3012.100            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1     grid_3.3.1      lattice_0.20-34 quadprog_1.5-5 
###############################################################################

EURUSD <- read.csv(file="EURUSD-2016-08.csv", header=FALSE) #from TrueFX
names(EURUSD)[names(EURUSD)=="V1"] <- "Symbol"
names(EURUSD)[names(EURUSD)=="V2"] <- "Date"
names(EURUSD)[names(EURUSD)=="V3"] <- "Bid"
names(EURUSD)[names(EURUSD)=="V4"] <- "Offer"
head(EURUSD)

   Symbol                  Date     Bid   Offer
1 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.018 1.11672 1.11675
2 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.141 1.11672 1.11677
3 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.142 1.11671 1.11677
4 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.143 1.11671 1.11676
5 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.146 1.11672 1.11676
6 EUR/USD 20160801 00:00:00.150 1.11673 1.11677

class(EURUSD)

[1] "data.frame"

EURUSD <- EURUSD[,-1]
options(digits.secs=3)
EURUSD <- xts(EURUSD[, 2:3], order.by=as.POSIXct(EURUSD[,1], format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
head(EURUSD)

               Bid   Offer
2016-08-01 1.11672 1.11675
2016-08-01 1.11672 1.11677
2016-08-01 1.11671 1.11677
2016-08-01 1.11671 1.11676
2016-08-01 1.11672 1.11676
2016-08-01 1.11673 1.11677

class(EURUSD)

[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

I know this issue has been covered in this blog before but I have been unable to get the right date format right to the milliseconds. Where am I going wrong?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds-in-r

Comment: Actually I have a coding error at the format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S" where  it should be %OS rather than %S. that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
options(digits.secs=3)
test <- "20160801 00:00:00.018"
as.POSIXct(test, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS")
```