# How to calculate time difference in milliseconds using R when formats are different?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a problem in R that is killing me! Can you help me?

I found a question in StackOverflow that gave me a very good explanation.

Here is the link: [How to parse milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds)

I was able to implement the following code that works very well.

```
z2 <- strptime("10/2/20 11:16:17.682", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
z1 <- strptime("10/2/20 11:16:16.683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
```

When I calculate ***z2-z1***, I get
***Time difference of 0.9989998 secs***

Similarly, when I use

```
z3 <- strptime("130 11:16:16.683", "%j %H:%M:%OS")
z4 <- strptime("130 11:16:18.682", "%j %H:%M:%OS")
```

When I calculate ***z4-z3***, I get
***Time difference of 1.999 secs***

What is my problem?

The first column has the format 130 18:25:50.408, with millions of rows!!!
The second column has the format ***2020*** 130 18:25:51.357 that is like the first column but has the year 2020.

The first column is also from 2020, but as the year is not there R uses the current year.

***First question,***

How can I substract both columns? I know how to substract columns.

What I do not know is to subtract these two times.

For example, second time is ***2020 130 18:25:51.357***
and first time is ***130 18:25:50.408***

I guess that I can do it programmatically converting it to a string, and eliminating the 2020. However, I am hoping that a quicker solution is available using base R or the ***lubridate*** package.

***Second question,***

`"%j %H:%M:%OS"` is the format for ***130 11:16:16.683***

What is the format for ***2020 130 18:25:51.357***?

***As explained before this is working very well:***

z3 <- strptime("130 11:16:16.683", "%j %H:%M:%OS")

***But, this is NOT working.***

z7 <- strptime("2020 130 11:16:16.683", "%y %j %H:%M:%OS")

### UPDATE 1

I solved the second question!

***However, I have not figured out yet the first question.***

For the second question, the mistake in the format was that instead of %y, I need to write %Y with upper case.

Here is one example:

```
later <- strptime("2020 130 11:16:17.683", "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS")
earlier <- strptime("2020 130 11:16:16.684", "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS")
difftime(later,earlier,units="secs")
```

The R results is:

***Time difference of 0.9990001 secs***

### UPDATE 2

At this point, what is pending is the following:

I need to substract two times that were made the same day on 2020.

The second time does have the year, the first time does not.

```
later <- strptime("2020 130 11:16:17.683", "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS")
earlier <- strptime("130 11:16:16.684", "%j %H:%M:%OS")
difftime(later,earlier,units="secs")
```

R produces the following result:
***Time difference of -31622399 secs***

Why? As we are on 2021, R formats the vector ***earlier*** as the current year, 2021 because the year is not there.

My columns has millions of rows.

At this point, my guess is that I would need to add 2020 with a concatenation or something like that. Is there any other method?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post some sample data, using `dupt(head(mydata))` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited the question. Please see "First question."

Comment: `strptime("20/2/06 11:16:17.682", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")`, are you sure that in your format-string the `%y` is in the correct position? You are currently reading day/month/year, so 20th February 2006, in stead of 6th February 2020...

Comment: Hi @Wimpel  Thanks for your help! The one that you wrote is working very well. The one that is NOT working is z7 <- strptime("2020 130 11:16:16.683", "%y %j %H:%M:%OS")

Comment: @Wimpel Also, the one that you wrote was an online example. The real ones are in the "First question." Here they are anyway: "second time is 2020 130 18:25:51.357 and first time is 130 18:25:50.408"

Comment: I edited the question for clarity about the part that you mentioned. However, please see the first question.

Comment: Please clean up your question. Remove _everything_ that you _don't_ need help with, and only keep what actually remains to be solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object z2 is a POSIX list object. What this means is that it is a list of the time elements of your time.

```
print.default(z2)
# $sec
# [1] 17.682
# 
# $min
# [1] 16
# 
# $hour
# [1] 11
# 
# $mday
# [1] 10
# 
# $mon
# [1] 1
# 
# $year
# [1] 120
# 
# $wday
# [1] 1
# 
# $yday
# [1] 40
# 
# $isdst
# [1] 0
# 
# $zone
# [1] "GMT"
# 
# $gmtoff
# [1] NA
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

When you do a subtraction, `z2 - z1` R dispatches this operation to a function called `-.POSIXt`, which itself calls `difftime`. This function converts z2 to a POSIX count object. What this means is that it gets converted to a count of seconds since the beginning of the epoch, by default "1970-01-01".

```
options("digits" = 16)
print.default(as.POSIXct(z2))
# [1] 1581333377.682
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# attr(,"tzone")
# [1] ""
difftime(z2, z1)
# Time difference of 0.9989998340606689 secs
```

R, like most software, works with [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numerics. This means that arithmetic is imprecise, although approximately true. Most software will try to hide this imprecision by reducing the number of digits shown. That said, different numbers will give you different imprecision, so you might prefer referring directly to the list element of z2.

```
print.default(z2$sec - z1$sec)
# [1] 0.9989999999999988
```

You could therefore apply the time difference using your favourite data.frame tools.

```
options("digits" = 6)
# character columns
df1 <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("10/2/20 11:16:17.682", "10/2/20 11:16:16.683"), 
    col2 = c("130 11:16:16.683", "130 11:16:18.682"), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
# convert columns to POSIXlt
df2 <- mutate(df1, 
    col1 = strptime(col1, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS"), 
    col2 = strptime(stringr::str_c("2020 ", col2), "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS"), 
    diff_days = unclass(difftime(col2, col1, units = "days")))
df2
# col1                col2                  diff_days
# 1 2020-02-10 11:16:17 2020-05-09 11:16:16   88.9583
# 2 2020-02-10 11:16:16 2020-05-09 11:16:18   88.9584
```

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer! However, it seems that I am not explaining myself properly. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Beginner yes, if the year is not provided you would need to append it.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me with this? This works. newtime <- "2020 130 11:16:17.683"
oldtime <- "130 11:16:16.684"
oldtime <- paste("2020", oldtime, sep=" ")
oldtime
later <- strptime(newtime, "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS")
earlier <- strptime(oldtime, "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS")
difftime(later,earlier,units="secs")

Comment: But this does not work. diff_seconds = difftime(df1$col2, df1$col1, units = "secs")) However, what you posted works.

Comment: What you posted was the following: df1 <- mutate(df1, 
    col1 = strptime(col1, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS"), 
    col2 = strptime(stringr::str_c("2020 ", col2), "%Y %j %H:%M:%OS"), 
    diff_days = unclass(difftime(col2, col1, units = "days")))

Comment: @Beginner I relabelled df1 to make it easier to follow what is happening. To begin with the date time is a character. We can apply a class to elements of a column, e.g. with `strptime`. At that stage you can use functions appropriate to that class. diff_seconds = difftime(df1$col2, df1$col1, units = "secs") does not work for df1 (character columns) but does work for df2 (POSIXlt columns)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the explanation!