# convert character containing hundredths of a second to a timestamp

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion, timestamp, character

`"09JUN2022:00:00:00.04"` is a character timestamp that I am trying to convert to a datetime format that has the date, time and hundredths of a second.

`strptime` with the format is what I have used before for timestamps but it doesn't convert this correctly

```
> strptime("09JUN2022:00:00:00.04", "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%OS")
[1] "2022-06-09 00:00:04 BST"
```

If I remove `%OS` it drops the time entirely

```
> strptime("09JUN2022:00:00:00.04", "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2022-06-09 BST"
```

`as.POSIXct` has the same behaviour

```
> as.POSIXct("09JUN2022:00:00:00.04",format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%OS")
[1] "2022-06-09 00:00:04 BST"
> as.POSIXct("09JUN2022:00:00:00.04",format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2022-06-09 BST"
```

**lubridate** does work but it requires me splitting up the string, is there a way to do it without that?
It also takes .01 off the hundredths which I can live with but unsure why.

```
> dmy("09JUN2022") + hms("00:00:00.04")
[1] "2022-06-09 00:00:00.03 UTC"
> dmy("09JUN2022") + hms("00:00:00.06")
[1] "2022-06-09 00:00:00.05 UTC"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds) - basically your syntax is slightly wrong, you want `"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%OS"` (i.e. just `"%OS"` rather than `"%S.%OS"`).

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, if you reply with this as answer I will accept it